# Xcode 9 Swift 4 Tabbed Page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I know how to use tabBarController.
But I dont Know How to Create A Tabbed Page Like The Attached Image.
Whats The Name Of This Type Of Tab?

Comment: https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu

Answer (score 2):

This is not any type of Tab. You can use a collectionView or a stackView  for "***Tabs***" and a **UIPageViewController** for changing viewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tab) for similar controls, download source code and check their construction. You can possible do it with SegmentedControls (Or Custom UIViews for single Tab and draw in ScrollView) and UIScrollView as Content View (with Pagination On) as well, but it depends how much customisation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Trust me, it's REALLY tricky to obtain what you want with the iOS components. There are a lot of details that you will miss.
When I tried myself to build the same thing, it was like "ok I think I am reinventing the wheel, is not straight forward as I though, it require a lot of work"
You know you have to consider a lot of stuff like an User that start to scroll as a crazy between the pages and then tap on one tab bar button, and so on. Trust me, it's easy to have a working implementation, but it's really  really difficult to obtain a PERFECT implementation

I decided to go for a library

- https://github.com/aokizen/SPSlideTabBarController
- https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

but there are others that are all good to achieve what you want

Anyway if you want to go for your personal implementation I suggest a Segmented Control in the upper side and a PageViewController (maybe inside a Container View)